# ASP.NET - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, https

We get the following error;

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

while using a `WebRequest` object to make an `HTTPS` request. The funny thing is that this only happens after a while, and is temporarily fixed when the application is restarted, which suggests that something is being filled to capacity or something.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall having this problem last year.  I suspect that you aren't closing your WebRequest objects properly, which is why after a certain amount of use it won't allow you to create any new connections.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem! 
I send two requisitions to an HTTPS webservice in close period range (seconds).
The first requisition works fine, but the second requisition fails.

I´ve tried to set "System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3", but the second requisition freezes...

I´m using VB.NET 2008.

Thanks

Comment: This actually fixed the problem for me and I doubt I would have found it if it wasn't for your post.  Hope you had better luck!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The similar problem for me fixed by:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be a Conenction: Keep-alive thing: http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2005/01/04/759.aspx#780

Comment: I get the "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" about once a day in one of my applications that handles a lot of transactions. I set the keep alive property to false and it didn't help any.