# C# Closing a HttpWebRequest DevDefined

Tags: c#, oauth, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, devdefined-oauth

I'm having a problem connecting to a 3rd party API using the DevDefined OAuth library for C#:

https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth

The connection has been working fine for over a year now, but in the last two days it has started failing every few hours.  The exception message is:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

It works as normal after the app pool has been restarted but then stops authenticating after a few hours - this makes me think that it is not closing the HttpWebRequest, and we are leaking connections and eventually running out.

A similar question suggests that KeepAlive might solve this, but it did not help me: [ASP.NET - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

But the code is quite complex, and the HttpWebRequest object is passed around to many other functions after being created.  I can't see where to close it.  And also, I don't know how to close a HttpWebRequest, so my question is:

- How can I find where to close this HttpWebRequest?
- How do you close a HttpWebRequest? Or is it the Response that must be disposed?

The DevDefined code looks like this:

```
public virtual HttpWebRequest ToWebRequest()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(description.Url);
    // .. snip setting request properties
    return request;
}
```

The function `ToWebRequest()` is called in several places, and from those places the Response is extracted and returned to even more methods.  So its proving to be difficult to track it down.  I did find this method that seems to show that the Response is being used but not disposed:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResponseBody))
    {
    ResponseBody = ToWebResponse().ReadToEnd();
    }
    return ResponseBody;
}
```

Comment: Try creating a system.net trace log for your application ( http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html ). It should show  you why the SSL handshake is failing.

Comment: @feroze - thanks I got tracing working.  But is is a massive log - is it possible to only log the connection attempt?  the log is massive on my local dev box - it's going to be real bad on our live server with 1000's of users.

Comment: How big is the file? Can you just grep through it for the SSL handshake failure?

Comment: 1,000's of users each making hundreds of requests an hour.  Its a big file.  But yes I did just search for the failure, and found the cause of the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232746/c-httpwebrequest-sec-i-renegotiate-intermittent-errors and I've put a fix in place, now just waiting to see if it fails again.

Comment: Was this problem ever resolved? - I have a similar problem connecting to Twitter from Amazon EC2 instances.

Comment: @Lee we solved it by making sure our app worked in 64 bit compilation mode and setting IIS allow 32 bit apps = false.